# EF repository Query method, how to mention other entity in expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In EF generic repoistory my  Query method is as below:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        return objectSet.Where(filter);
    }
```

I have used this method to filter data like:

```
Repository.Query(a=>a.EntityId==selectedId);
```

Below is my tables structure.

1. Entity (Id, Name)
2. Title (Id,Name,EntityId)
3. Level (Id, Name,TitleId)

I know EntityId and based I want to filter data from Level table but Entity and Levle table are not connected directly, Level is attaching them.

Please guide how I should write write lambda expression to pass to Query method.

Thanks

**Edit**
ObjectSet type is Level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using standard names for your navigation properties you should be able to do this:

```
Repository.Query(level => level.Title.Entity.EntityId == selectedId);
```

If not, can you post your model?